# How to convert .msi file for windows 10 UWP apps

Tags: windows-10, uwp, winjs

I'm working in windows 10 UWP cordova application and my client wants setup as .msi. How could I convert my .appxbundle to .msi?

Is there any proven option to create windows 10 UWP app package as .msi file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to create msi file.

But you can side load your app. You can find at the end of this article 
[Packaging UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) how to sideload app package. You should run with Powershell file **Add-AppDevPackage.ps1** and follow instructions.

Probably, you can create some exe file that could copy files to machine and run this script in Powershell

Comment: Yeah I've only found the side loading option. Other thing to point out is the ability to skip the power shell script and directly open the `.appxbundle` on newer versions of Windows 10.